# When are slack terms support vectors in soft-margin SVM?

Tags: svm

I know that slack terms can be used as support vectors, such as here on slide 19:
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect2.pdf
But does that mean that slack terms are always support vectors?